# Refresh picture gallery programaticaly (on SD card)

Tags: android, image-gallery, android-broadcast

i have programed tool that moves pictures from one folder (internal storage) to SD CARD every 10 soconds. I m trying to refresh gallery after that but problem is after calling broadcast nothing happens:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, file.getUri));
```

because file is not File but DocumentFile (since i need to read/write from SD) and thats the only way i can do it AFAIK.
uri of DocumentFile looks like

`content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/0000-0000%3Adownload/document/0000-0000%3Adownload%2F20200723_113009.jpg`

Any idea how to solve it? Thank you

Comment: You can very easy convert your content scheme to a file system path In your case it would be /storage/0000-000/download/20200723_113009.jpg and then try to let that path be scanned in the usual way. Untested.

Comment: But you could also not use SAF but the MediaStore to copy your files to that location. Then you are directly done.

Comment: Reboot your device and all is scanned by the MediaStore hence Gallery apps will know.

Comment: 1) /storage/0000-0000/download/20200723_113009.jpg unfortunately doesnt work

2) Unfortunately MediaStore doesnt provide folder i want to use ("downlaod"  folder is just example; i try to copy photos from internal storage to sd/DCIM/camera)

3) rebooting phone after every picter being moved is not a option

Comment: Please give exact uri. As you have seen you already confused me. All takes time.

Comment: Thats the thing. i dont know exact uri which points to files in SD card...Uri i get from DocumetFile obejct is in main question: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/0000-0000%3Adownload/document/0000-0000%3Adownload%2F20200723_113009.jpg. Exact Uri u r asking for is actualy what Im asking for :D or another solution for my problem, which is refreshing gallery pictures stored on SD card

Comment: If you used that to copy that file then it is an exact uri and the corresponding file system path would be  /storage/0000-000/download/20200723_113009.jpg as i said before. And it has nothing to do with a sd/DCIM/camera path as you told later. I cannot follow you.

Comment: I m not copying file. 1) I create file on sd card using DocumentFile object "createFile" method(only way im aware of creating a file on sd card on location user specify) 2) i fill data to empty created file from original photo using output/input strem. so Uri im able to get is only through DocumentFile object which is this "content://com.android.externalstorage...."

Comment: So you are copying files from file system to SAF. Ok. And that is well done i see. So that is your uri.

Comment: Hm but then i have method "refreshGallery" which send broadcast  with Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, and i pass pictureUri as load. for the files from internal storage it works and really refresh gallery, but if i pass uri from sd card picture in format ""content://com.and...." newly created picture file on SD keeps no thumbnail and cant be oppened untill some random background android job index/refresh it (without reboot needed)

Comment: `and i pass pictureUri as load` Please give an exact example of such an uri. The value of uri.toString().;

Comment: this one from internal storage which works - file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20200723_172541.jpg
this one from SD card which doesnt work - content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/0000-0000%3Adownload/document/0000-0000%3Adownload%2F20200723_172541.jpg
also tried  this one as previos comments  /storage/0000-000/download/20200723_172541.jpg and didnt work

Comment: But that is a file uri. Not a content scheme uri. Did you try file:///storage/0000-000/download/20200723_113009.jpg ?

Comment: Yes jsut did with no result :-/

Comment: But strange is in another "gallery app" (not my default one) pictures appears from SD even without calling my refresh method... so i think my default galerry app is just trashy...